# Difference over a date range in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQl table storing time based data defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `values` (
    `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `SOURCEID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `VALUE` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `LASTUPDATE` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

and I need to display the difference between the first and the last value of VALUE for each month for each SOURCEID.
Is there anybody so kind to suggest me how to approach?

What I tried till now is something in the form of

```
select 
    8 myid,
    1 mymonth,
    (select value from values v where month(v.lastupdate)=mymonth and v.sourceid=myid order by lastupdate desc limit 1) -
(select value from values v where month(v.lastupdate)=mymonth and v.sourceid=myid order by lastupdate limit 1)
```

from values
limit 1;

This way I am able to obtain the difference between last and first VALUE for month 1 and SOURCEID 8.
It would be already very useful to retrieve the differences for all the sources for a given month

Thank you

Comment: Please post your expected output details.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO ist not a free programming service. Show what you came up with and people here will gladly help you.